# How to start a javascript function from another function

Tags: javascript, function

I don't know how simple this would be but I am trying to figure out how to call a function from a function.

I have an JavaScript to show a DIV on a Page and I have another JavaScript that uses a appenchild to call an image. My problem is that I cant have that image loaded before the first JavaScript is executed. This is more than just display or not the image before, I need the image to be called only after the first JavaScript is loaded.

The image is a dynamically generated and is used to track the action of showing the DIV. If I let the browser load the image before the action it defeat the tracking purpose.

the the code I want to load after the DIV is loaded:

```
function MonitorDIVExpand() {
    var img = document.createElement('img');
    img.src = "http://dynamically generated image";
    ClickExpandArea.appendChild(img);
}
```

and this is the one that shows de DIV:

```
function ShowDIV() {
    document.getElementById('div').style.clip='rect(0px, ' + width_xp + 'px, ' + height_xp + 'px, 0px)';
    document.getElementById('div').style.width=width_xp + 'px';
    document.getElementById('div').style.display='block';
    document.getElementById('div').style.overflow='visible';
}
```

And then I have this div to call the image:

```
<div id="ClickExpandArea"></div>
```

Is that a way to do this??? 
thank you in advance guys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add `MonitorDIVExpand()` at the end of `ShowDIV()` (just before the closing `}`)

Comment: Technically it's optional anyway, but you should put the `;` in.